# iOS Swift Local notification not "popping up"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications, local

I'm trying to send a local notification at scheduled time. But the notifications does not appear on the screen, but it is showing in the notification center when I swipe down.  
This is what I'm trying to achieve         This is what I getting.
[image]       [image]   [image]

This code is from my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions().

```
    // Setup local push notifications
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil))
    scheduleNotifications()
```

And this is the code for scheduleNotifications()

```
func scheduleNotifications() {
    // create a corresponding local notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    // Get today's date, time and year
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate: NSDate())
    // Sets the fire time to 2pm/1400 hours to anticipate user for lunch time
    components.hour = 19
    components.minute = 13
    components.second = 00

    notification.fireDate = components.date             // Sets the fire date
    notification.alertBody = "Enjoyed your lunch? Don't forget to track your expenses!"
    notification.alertAction = "Add expense"
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day    // Repeats the notifications daily

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In iOS Settings > Your App  are the permission settings set right? Specifically, check the setting for 'Show on Lock Screen'.  Also, can you please post the payload you are sending with the push notification.

Comment: Yes its set to show on lockscreen. And what do you mean by payload? This is all the code I wrote for the notifications.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking of a push notification rather than a local notification, which has a payload. Are you are scheduling far enough into the future so that the notification is received _after_ you lock the device?

Comment: Yes I did. I scheduled it 2 minutes to give it some extra time but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is the way you are converting the NSDateComponents object to an NSDate.

Simply calling `components.date` without setting a `calendar` for the `NSDateComponents` object will return `nil`.

Try using this instead:

```
 notification.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

Alternatively, you can set the `calendar` property on the components object:

```
components.calendar = calendar
```

Because you are setting the `fireDate` property on the notification object to `nil`, it will fire immediately, i.e. before you have a chance to close the app and lock the screen. This behavour is documented in the [UILocalNotification class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW13)

Answer (score 2):

To me, when phone is connected with a cable, then notification shows up only in notification center - banner is not displayed when app is in foreground.
When cable is disconnected, then the banner is presented over the app.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same odd behavior. Just created a new project to test your code.

What i noticed when you change your fireDate to:

```
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
```

You will get your wanted behavior.

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: I just tried that out and it works! But what I wanted to do is to schedule it so that it would repeat everyday at that same time. Not sure why using calendar components didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Settings > YourApp > Notifications**.

Verify the permissions there. "Do Not Disturb" should also not be active.

[image]

Comment: Yes, everything is turned on. But still can't get it to show though. It doesn't show even if the phone is unlocked. Tried using banners, and alerts as well.

Comment: All these permissions turned ON. But still, I don't get the notifications.

Comment: @Ashvini The results will depend on your code but I've added the "Do Not Disturb" setting that can also affect display of notifications.